# Can't understand what is wrong, get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, any hints?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having this sprite with this in it's init method

```
lineDrawer = [[LineDrawer alloc]initWithLineColor:ccc3(color.r, color.g, color.b)];
lineDrawer.position = ccp(0,0);
lineDrawer.anchorPoint = ccp(1,1);

[self addChild:lineDrawer];
[self addChild:head];

[lineDrawer release];
```

Nothing wrong here right? I can release it as addchild is retaining the object.
(autorelease would also be ok)

Although when I have the release I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1) later on. I've also tried to move the release to the dealloc method but it gives me the same error.

The only object that has reference to lineDrawer is the spriteobject (Player : CCSprite) it's *defined in* and It doesn't have a getter so it cant even be accessed by another object, so I don't see how this can happen. What can be calling lineDrawer at the time It's dealloced when only the owner has a reference to it?

It happens on the line  CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP() inside the draw method of CCLayer.

Any hints? I know these questions is always hard to solve with the lack of code but It's really hard to know what code to show you. If I knew I could probably solve it by myself. I've also tried to debug this some in instruments but I'm not sure where to look.

**Update**, 
I tried debugging with zombies enabled

[image: This is the result]

Does this say anything to you? 
This is the LineDrawer class. It's someone else's class that I've slightly modified.

http://pastebin.com/7Uv4GULy 
http://pastebin.com/08NHeVt9

I have a feeling that its some method that's scheduled or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you add the `lineDrawer` object to the child collection of your `CCSprite`, a public reference to it is available through the `.children` property defined in `CCNode`.

However, nothing in the code you've posted seems wrong, except that `LineDrawer` inherits from `CCLayer` and I don't think that `CCLayer` was ever designed to be used as a child of a `CCSprite` ... does it really need to be a child of your Player object? (e.g. should it be following your Player sprite as it moves and rotates?) Typically a layer is a child of your active `CCScene` node, or another layer.

Comment: Yes but the crash happens after I dealloc the Player class so the childrens should be emptied right (and released)

About the other thing, It might seem a bit weird, but It's actually part of the playersprite so it makes sense to me. Maybe it should be LineDrawer:CCSprite, but as you say it shouldn't matter. Im trying to track it down the CCLOG way now, just so frustrating everytime this happens as I'm so unused to debbuging in xcode or C in general.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these problems don't happen anymore when you are [using ARC](https://github.com/LearnCocos2D/cocos2d-iphone-arc-templates).

Most likely you have over-released an object. It doesn't necessarily need to be the lineDrawer. Perhaps it's an object inside the lineDrawer class.

Best way to figure this out is to enable NSZombieObjects in the build scheme and find out which object was accessed.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. However I don't see any problems with LineDrawer. I've updated my post with results from enabling zombies, not sure if it helps you though.